# iOS - handling redirects in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have this bool function in web view that checks for the keyword "youtube" and if there is a keyword "youtube" in a link it will open in app web view instead of safari.This works correctly, but there is a problem that I ran into. If the youtube link is shortened by https://bitly.com/ it will open in safari. Is there a way to prevent this. I still need the https://bitly.com/ to open in safari for every other keyword except youtube.

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
 if ([[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"youtube"].location==NSNotFound){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: The only way I know of to do this is to check the link for redirects manually (e.g. NSURLConnection).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**knowurl**](http://knowurl.com) service to expand original URL from tiny shortened link

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType 
 {
      @try
         {
           BOOL _returnVal = YES;

          //convert your bitly url to KowUrl if its contains `bit.ly`

          if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) 
          {
              if ([[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"youtube"].location==NSNotFound)
              {
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
                 _returnVal =  NO;
              }
           }
      }
      @catch (NSException *exception)
      {
         NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
      }
     @finally
     {
       return loadedImages;
     }    
}
```